# Requests Get and Flask Mail Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-mail

```
msg.html = requests.get("http://2teso.com/cachedigital/themail.html")
mail.send(msg)
```

I don't want to use something like this:

```
msg.html = """
<p>Hey</p>
"""
```

Which works by the way.

I would just like to ref a file. How can I do this?

I thought I could use the request module.

To clarify the first code block does not input the html into the email.
If I write html code directly in the python app, then it works and the email send.

I want to send an html email by pointing to a file or url.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response content of an URL using `text` attribute of response from `requests` package.

Here is an example of how to get HTML contents from an URL using `requests` package.

`code.py`:

```
import requests


r = requests.get('https://example.com/')
content = r.text
print(type(content))
print(content)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        div {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-radius: 0;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally you can change the encoding by setting encoding in `r.encoding` (e.g.: `r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'`). If you change the encoding, Requests will use the new value of `r.encoding` whenever you call `r.text`.

After getting the HTML contents of the desired URL using `requests`, assign it to `msg.html` to send the content in the email.

Code can be updated like this:

```
import requests


r = requests.get('https://example.com/')
content = str(r.text)
msg.html = content
mail.send(msg)
```

**Reference:**

- [Documentation on response content of requests package](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)